# Sqlite and jquery variable in for loop setting to last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, variables, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through all of the tables in my Sqlite DB and send them to the server DB. Everything is working except when I get to the part where I send the information via a $.get() the tbl_name variable is already set to the last value... IE all of the $.get() calls use the same value for tbl_name, the last table name.

```
        var submissionID=10;
        var varStr;

        DEMODB.transaction(function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';", [], function(transaction, results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    var tables = results.rows.item(i);
                    var tbl_name=tables['name'];

                    if (tbl_name=="__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__" || tbl_name=="Submission") { continue; }

                    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM " + tbl_name + " WHERE submissionID=?;", [ID], function(transaction, results) {
                        varStr="";
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = results.rows.item(i);

                            for (col in row) {
                                if (col=="submissionID" || col=="ID") { continue; }
                                varStr += col + "=" + row[col] + '&';
                            }
                        }
                        varStr += 'submissionID=' + submissionID + "&table=" + tbl_name + "&num=" + i;
                        $.get("script/to/process.aspx",varStr);
                    }, errorHandler);
                }
            }, errorHandler);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DEMODB.transaction(function (transaction) {
  transaction.executeSql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';", [], function(transaction, results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      var tables = results.rows.item(i);
      handleTable(tables['name'], transaction);
    }
  }, errorHandler);
});


function handleTable(tbl_name, transaction) {

  if (tbl_name=="__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__" || tbl_name=="Submission") { return; }

  transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM " + tbl_name + " WHERE submissionID=?;", [ID], function(transaction, results) {
    varStr="";
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      var row = results.rows.item(i);

      for (col in row) {
        if (col=="submissionID" || col=="ID") { continue; }
        varStr += col + "=" + row[col] + '&';
      }
    }
    varStr += 'submissionID=' + submissionID + "&table=" + tbl_name + "&num=" + i;
    $.get("script/to/process.aspx",varStr);
  }, errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I've been pulling my hair out on this for a couple hours.